# Cómo compartir información entre funciones

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo obtener la información de la variable *bar1* desde cualquier otra función que necesite esa información...

Este ejemplo de código entrego la información desde *bar0* a *bar1* pero necesito que cualquier función pueda obtener la información de la *bar1*.

¿Cómo las enlazo para poder hacerlo?

```js
function bar0() {

bar1("Información entregada desde bar0");

}

function bar1(informacionDesdeBar0) {

console.log(informacionDesdeBar0); // Información recibida

$.ajax({

url: "example.com",
type: "GET",
error: function(v) {

console.log(v);

}

});

}

function /*Función que requiera la información*/() {

// Cómo obtener la información de la función bar1



}
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes es pedirle a una función que te guarde algo, y que después te lo pase. La función se olvida de lo que tiene dentro después de haberse ejecutado.

Debes guardar esa información en una variable global, o puedes crear un objeto con toda la lógica

```js
let MiObjeto = {
 bar0 : function(){
  this.bar1("Información entregada desde bar0");
 },
 bar1 : function(informacionDesdeBar0){
  this.InforGuardada = informacionDesdeBar0;
 }
};

MiObjeto.bar0();

console.log(MiObjeto.InforGuardada);
```

Otra forma de escribir lo mismo

```js
class Algo
{
  bar0(){
     this.bar1("Información entregada desde bar0");
  }
  bar1(informacionDesdeBar0){
    this.InforGuardada = informacionDesdeBar0;
  }
}

let MiObjeto = new Algo();
MiObjeto.bar0();

console.log(MiObjeto.InforGuardada);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando returns, promesas o callbacks:

```
function bar1(datos) {
  //hago cosas con datos
  return resultado; //devuelvo algo
}

function bar2(datos) {
  const resultadoBar1 = bar1(datos); // guardo el resultado obtenido
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success : bar3 //hago una llamada AJAX y la respuesta se la paso a bar3
  }

  // otra forma de hacer lo mismo
  fetch("https:// ...")
    .then(response => response.json()) //asumo una respuesta JSON
    .then(bar3);
}

function bar3(respuestaAjax) {
  ... // procesa los datos obtenidos 
}
```

Lo importante es entender la diferencia entre los flujos asíncronos y síncronos